# Trying to scrape hidden download links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, screen-scraping

I am attempting to scrape a website for download links, but the links are written out like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="addondownload" id="addondownload" >
    <input type="hidden" name="addonid" id="addonid" value="2109" />
    <input class="red_btn" type="submit" name="send" value="Download Now!" />
</form>
```

and the only thing i can find that relates to this that would produce a download link of any sort is a jQuery file:

**download_addon.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// prepare Options Object 
var options5 = { 
    url:        url,
    data:       { action : 'downloadfileaddon' },
    success:    function(e) { 
        //alert(e); 
        //var count = e.length - 1;
        var check = e.substring(0,5); 
        if(check == 'http:'){   
            //var url = e.substring(0,count);
            window.location = e;
        }else{
            alert(e);
        }
    } 
};

// pass options to ajaxForm 
jQuery('#addondownload').ajaxForm(options5);
```

});

My question is, is this file responsible for returning the download link the user's browser? If so, is there a way to simulate the passing of data to this file in a php script? Perhaps in a cURL request?

Comment: You need to send a POST request to the page with the parameter `addonid` set to the ID of the add-on you want to download, and the server's response will probably redirect to the file's location or will be the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a bit of digging and some wireshark business, it turns out that the post should look like this:

```
$url = "http://www.website.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    "addonid" => $mod_id,
    "send" => "Download+Now!",
    "action" => "downloadfileaddon"
    )
));
```

It seems as though calling the post the website frontpage was not what needed to be done, and in fact it was a php script that is not included on the html for the website!

Good old wireshark!